# how read excel (.xlxs ) using IExcelDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel sheet and in that, I have data in numbers.

```
|test |vertical|horizonatl|straight|top|Bottom|
|First| 20     |   30     |   15   | 6 |  9   |
|Secon| 10     |   20     |   30   | 4 |  3   |
```

I want to read the top and bottom into my List. I tried to use IExcelDataReader

```
string filePath = (@"C:Values.xlsx");

FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
    
foreach (DataColumn col in result.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in result.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine(row[col.ColumnName].ToString());
        a = row[col.ColumnName].ToString();
    }
}
```

If I use this then the code starts reading the first column and first row and keeps on reading in a column. I tried to make Table[4] and Table [1].

Not sure how to get this code working.

Comment: "I want to read the top and bottom" = "I want to read the top and bottom row"?

Comment: read items under the top and bottom columns in two lists

Answer (score 0):

Provided top and bottom contain integers, the below code should work:

```
string filePath = (@"C:Values.xlsx");

FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

DataSet dataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet();
DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];

DataColumn topColumn = table.Columns["top"];
DataColumn bottomColumn = table.Columns["Bottom"];

var tops = new List<int>();
var bottoms = new List<int>();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    int top = (int)row[topColumn];
    tops.Add(top);

    int bottom = (int)row[topColumn];
    bottoms.Add(top);
}
```

You could also use [Linq to dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/linq-to-dataset):

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable())
{
    int top = row.Field<int>(topColumn);
    tops.Add(top);

    int bottom = row.Field<int>(topColumn);
    bottoms.Add(top);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, this code crashes with the error: ''column' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: column'  DataColumn topColumn = table.Columns["top"]; seems to get null value

Comment: @user583088 Probably because the name of column 'Bottom' starts with a capital letter, please try the updated code (are you sure the crash is on the 'top' line?)

Comment: yes , i am using debugger , DataColumn topColumn = table.Columns["top"];

Comment: Then are you sure the name of the column in Excel is 'top' (case matters)?

Comment: i even chnaged my .xlxs as    so there are only two columns                                                                       |top|Bottom|                                                                                                                          | 6  |  9       |                                                                                                                       | 4  |  3       |

Comment: yes it is top and another one is Bottom , if you want to change the string I can change that also

Comment: What do `table.Columns[0].ColumnName` and `table.Columns[1].ColumnName` show in debug?

Comment: DataColumn topColumn = table.Columns[0].ColumnName; is this the way to use it

Comment: No, `table.Columns[0].ColumnName` returns a `string`, not a `DataColumn`

Comment: i get Column0 and Column1 as return                                                                                 s = table.Columns[0].ColumnName;
s1= table.Columns[1].ColumnName;

Comment: It's probably because the data in your spreadsheet is not formatted as a table. Either skip the first line and user Column0 and Column1 for column names (or indices) or format as a table in Excel

Comment: if I am changing top and Bottom to Column0 and Column1 I am getting crash at             int top = (int)row[topColumn]; Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: Hence my comment to skip the first line (which contains the column names), replace `foreach (DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable())` with `foreach (DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable().Skip(1))`

Comment: I am not seeing foreach (DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable()) anywhere used in the code

Comment: It's in the Linq to dataset section

Comment: if i replace foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) with foreach (DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable().Skip(1)) . i am still getting crash crash at int top = (int)row[topColumn]; Specified cast is not valid. i even formatted the excel sheet

Comment: even in the Linq code i am getting crash at int top = row.Field<int>(topColumn);, as topColumn is  DataColumn topColumn = table.Columns["Column0"];

Answer (score 0):

Or in LINQ sql

```
        foreach (var (row, top) in from DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable()
                                   let top = row.Field<int>(topColumn)
                                   select (row, top))
        {
            tops.Add(top);
            int bottom = row.Field<int>(topColumn);
            bottoms.Add(top);
        }
```

A small typo as well

```
DataTable table = result.Tables[0];
```

should be

```
DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: I believe the last remark was intended to me... fixed, thanks

Comment: i figured that out , but i am getting crash DataColumn topColumn = table.Columns["top"]; error: ''column' argument cannot be null.